# Should we break the default case in switch statement?

Tags: c, switch-statement, break

Assuming this example code ([source](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson5.html)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void playgame()
{
    printf( "Play game called" );
}
void loadgame()
{
    printf( "Load game called" );
}
void playmultiplayer()
{
    printf( "Play multiplayer game called" );
}

int main()
{
    int input;

    printf( "1. Play game\n" );
    printf( "2. Load game\n" );
    printf( "3. Play multiplayer\n" );
    printf( "4. Exit\n" );
    printf( "Selection: " );
    scanf( "%d", &input );
    switch ( input ) {
        case 1:            /* Note the colon, not a semicolon */
            playgame();
            break;
        case 2:
            loadgame();
            break;
        case 3:
            playmultiplayer();
            break;
        case 4:
            printf( "Thanks for playing!\n" );
            break;
        default:
            printf( "Bad input, quitting!\n" );
            break;
    }
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

should we use a `break;` in the **last** `default` case? If I remove it, I see the same behaviour of the program. However, I saw that other examples also use a `break;` in the `default` case.

Why? Is there a reason?

Comment: You don't *need* a `break` after *any* case label if it is the last one. Whether it is `default` or otherwise has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Using the option `-pedantic` recent versions of gcc warn about a missing `break` after the last `case`.

Comment: @alk I was warned by Eclipse, without this flag. Here is the compilation command: `gcc -std=c99 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.c"`. Maybe `-Wall` was enough for that.

Comment: "*Maybe -Wall was enough for that.*": Even better! :-)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

> Should we use a break; in the last default case?

From *The C programming language - Second edition* (K&R 2):

**Chapter 3.4 Switch**

> As a matter of good form, put a break after the last case (the default
>   here) even though it's logically unnecessary. Some day when another
>   case gets added at the end, this bit of defensive programming will
>   save you.

Answer (score 15):

For one thing, you should think about why we should use `break` in switch statement. Look at this no-breaking switch statement.

```
switch ( input ) {
    case 1:            /* Note the colon, not a semicolon */
        playgame();
    case 2:
        loadgame();
    case 3:
        playmultiplayer();
    case 4:
        printf( "Thanks for playing!\n" );
    default:
        printf( "Bad input, quitting!\n" );
}
```

Suppose `input == 1`. The program will call `playgame()` of course, but since there's no `break`, program won't finish the `switch` but call `loadgame()`, `playmultiplayer()`, two `printf`s sequentially.

To avoid this, we use `break`.

```
case 1:
    playgame();
    break; /* here */
case 2:
    ...
```

Because of `break`, the program finishes `switch` statement before running codes of `case 2`. That's our expected result, isn't it?

Your switch is this:

```
switch ( input ) {
    case 1:            /* Note the colon, not a semicolon */
        playgame();
        break;
    case 2:
        loadgame();
        break;
    case 3:
        playmultiplayer();
        break;
    case 4:
        printf( "Thanks for playing!\n" );
        break;
    default:
        printf( "Bad input, quitting!\n" );
        break;
}
```

Since there's no `case`s after `default`, there's no effect whether you write `break` on `default` or not. **However**, you can easily suppose to write a new case.

```
    default:
        printf( "Thanks for playing!\n" );
        /* what happens if there's no `break`...? */
    case 5:
        the_new_feature();
        break;
}
```

It's **common-mistakes** in C/C++. If you add new feature after 5 years and you completely forget it, it'll become a *very buggy* bug. Some modern language (e.g. C#, ...) even *forbid* switch-case without `break` or `return`.

Conclusion: There's no problem *in syntax*, but it's very bad practice and using `break` is highly recommended.

Comment: Is it even allowed to have a _case_ after _default_?

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes it is

Answer (score 10):

It depends on **How default case is written**.

In the following case **break** is neccessary.

```
switch ( input ) {
    default:
        printf( "Bad input, quitting!\n" );
        break;
    case 1:            /* Note the colon, not a semicolon */
        playgame();
        break;
    case 2:
        loadgame();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Correct, but the question meant that the default case was last. I will edit, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

if `default` case is at last then `break` statement have no use. if it is before any other `case` then `break` is required. since usually we are putting `default` at the end so you can omit it..

Comment: Not only the `default` case,but all the cases is applicable here

Comment: @Cool Guy yes.. but he were asking abt default case.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no difference** if you omit or if you leave the `break` statement. It is a matter of taste.

However, it is good practice to write the break statement for different reasons.

Take a look at [programmers exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201777/break-on-default-case-in-switch).

Answer (score 1):

### Break Seems to Be Optional

`break` seems to be optional in that case. and also your code will work almost fine.

### However

in many situations adding break improves your code and protect your code from errors/exceptions.

it increases readability, consistency and more error free.

> some language like C# break(or other control-flow statement that exits the case) is technically needed after the last alternative. [dan04](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/12609/dan04)

so for better programming practices i suggest one should use it.

see this [excellent post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201777/break-on-default-case-in-switch) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need the break in default case. And as your checking, it's the same if you don't have break in default case.

But in my opinion, you should have the break in default case, because:

1. It make your code is have a form in every case.
2. It's good with current compiler but maybe not with specific other compiler. So you should make it good well to prevent issue from future.

Comment: The behavior here is same for all compilers