# What's the difference between char and int in a switch case?

Tags: c++

I started C++ recently and while learning switch case, I got this doubt.
What's the difference if I use int or char in the following code :
`int Fav_Car;`
The switch case code is as follows

```
switch( Fav_Car ) {
    case '1' :
        cout<< "That's cool";
        break;
    case '2' :
        cout<< "Even mine!";
        break;
    default :
        cout<< "Oh";
        break;
}
```

When I ran the program, I noticed that using int returns me the default case and using char works perfectly. Why does it happen so?
And also, what's the difference if I use `case '1' :` and `case "1" :`

Comment: You don't need a break in default.

Comment: [Couldn't reproducle](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WfEFMvLY08JxpEmn).. This statement works fine with `int`. Your input routine should be wrong.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MathewsMathai - it's ok to break in default - actually it's a good thing.

Comment: @artm Is there any use of doing it. default is the last block and it would practically make no differene (or does it??).

Comment: @MathewsMathai - yes there is, it's NOT guaranteed that a default is always the last one. See this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138994/should-we-break-the-default-case-in-switch-statement

Comment: @artm Oh I see. Chances of adding a new block later. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your misunderstanding has nothing to do with the `switch()` construct, it's all about the single quotes `''`: If you write `1`, you get an integer of the value 1, when you put it in single quotes `'1'`, you get the numeric value of the ASCII character for the digit 1 (this is a bit imprecise, see note below). That ASCII character has the numeric value of `0x31`, or `49` in decimal. Now imagine the difference between

```
switch( Fav_Car ) {
    case 1 :
        cout<< "That's cool";
        break;
    case 2 :
        cout<< "Even mine!";
        break;
    default :
        cout<< "Oh";
        break;
}
```

and

```
switch( Fav_Car ) {
    case 49 :
        cout<< "That's cool";
        break;
    case 50 :
        cout<< "Even mine!";
        break;
    default :
        cout<< "Oh";
        break;
}
```

The second one is equivalent to the version that you posted, and I think it's clear why it behaves very differently from the first version.

---

Note:
While `'1'` yields an ASCII character value in most C++ implementations, that does not need to be the case. The implementation is free to use some other character code, so that the value of `'1'` is actually implementation defined. It could be virtually anything except zero (because that's used for the terminating null-byte in strings). However, most implementations do use ASCII encoding, which is why I assumed ASCII in the text above.

Comment: No C++ standard requires use of the ASCII character set.   There are real-world standardised character sets for which `'0' != 48`, and nothing preventing a C++ implementation from employing one.

Comment: To underscore what @Peter said: many (almost all?) systems use ASCII, but the C++ standard does not, and should not, require ASCII. The gist of this answer is correct; it's just the assumption that all the world is ASCII that's encoding-ist.

Comment: @Peter Of course, you are correct, and I already asked myself how long it would take for someone to notice that little imprecision. I only referred to ASCII to avoid unnecessary complexity in the answer, and because I simply didn't have the time to hone my answer more. I have added a note now (and a reference to that note at the appropriate point of the text) to take care of this issue. Hope you like it :-)

Answer (score 3):

> What's the difference between char and int in a switch case?

Using `char` or `int` are both ok in a `switch` statement. It depends on how you input your `Fav_Car` - as long as the input matches with a `case`, that `case` will be executed.

Note that `char` is also an integral type - it has a value in range [32, 127] (assume you want a printable char).

> what's the difference if I use case '1' : and case "1"

`switch` `case` only work with integral (ie `int`, `char`). So:

```
case '1':   // ok.

case "1":   // wrong because "1" is a string - not integral type.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Why does it happen? Because in your switch case, you use a char, not int.

What is the difference between them?

```
1 //int
'1' // char 1
"1" // string 1
```

To use int

```
int a;
switch(a){
    case 1 :
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Got it now.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `'1'` is not the same thing as `1`.

`'1'` means the *printable* '1' character literal, which on any computer using the [ASCII character map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is actually the integer 49.

For a demonstration of the difference, try this:

```
char a = 1;
char b = '1';
int x  = a;
int y =  b;
cout << "a as int: " << x << "\n";
cout << "b as int: " << y;
```

Answer (score 1):

because '1' is a char and 1 is an integer. If you want to make integers work , remove the single quotes.
Using double quotes makes it a string.

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that INT is not working?

The following code works well:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int fav_car = 2;
switch(fav_car) {
        case 1 :
            std::cout<< "That's cool";
        break;
        case 2 :
            std::cout<< "Even mine!";
        break;
        default :
            std::cout<< "Oh";
        break;
    }
}
```

case '1' - it is a symbol

case "1" - it is a string constant

Comment: Got it acutally, I was using case '1' even when I declared Fav_Car as an integer, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Characters in switch cases are eventually converted to [ASCII](http://ascii.cl/) equivalent decimal i.e

```
char '1' - int 49 
char '2' - int 50
```

For example, if input is *integer* `int 1` , switch case will switch to `default` because `1` doesn't satisfy any case.

```
1 != 49
1 != 50
```

However, in case input is *character* `char '1'`, output will be the first case as your desire.

Answer (score 0):

In this case: none; there is no difference in the way your program will execute its `switch` statement. Both `char` and `int` are Integral Types: they represent integers. `char` is typically unsigned and at least 8 bits (0-255) and `int` is signed and typically 32-bits (-2 billion to + 2 billion).

Note that `char` represents a single character, not a string; and that you cannot use a string value in a `switch` statement in the way you can in C#, Java and Swift, as `switch` compiles-down to an in-memory hashtable for ultra-fast performance, that optimization cannot be done with string types currently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: "`char` is unsigned" No, it is implementation-defined whether a `char` object can hold negative values, according to [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 3.9.1 Fundamental types, and [it is signed in gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bAYQ161hY8paRBJ6).

Comment: @MikeCAT I have qualified my answer