# Linked List with multiple elements and finding the largest

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

As I was creating a linked list to replicate an expense manager, I got stuck with finding the day with the largest expense. I somehow managed to find the maximum value of the `total` through traversal but couldn't print the `day` associated with it. Please help.

My structure's code:

```c
struct node{
int day;
int movies;
int groceries;
int travel;
int total;
struct node* left;
struct node* right;
};
```

```c
void find_max()
{
    struct node *new1 = start;
    int max, c;
    if(start == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        max = start->total;
        while(new1 != NULL) {
            if(new1->total > max)
            {
                max = new1->total;
            }
            new1 = new1->right;
        }
    }
printf("The maximum spending was: %d",max);
}
```

Here when I try to print `new1->day` (I am not sure what this is called. Is this a branch?), it shows me a garbage value or stops running.

How do I display it correctly?

Edit (Code):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
int day;
int movies;
int groceries;
int travel;
int total;
struct node* left;
struct node* right;
};

void maximumNode();

//Main goes here, where I choose the option using switch case. Say the example is case 3

case 3:
        {
            maximumNode();
            break;
        }

//End of main

void maximumNode() {
    struct node *new1 = start;
    struct node *max;

    if(start == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty\n");
        return;
    }

    else {
        max->total = start->total;
        while(new1 != NULL) {
            if(new1->total > max->total)
            {
                max->total = new1->total;
            }
            new1 = new1->right;
        }
    }
printf("The maximum spending was: %d and the day was: %d\n\n",max->total, max->day);
}
```

Here, as soon as I type in case 3 after adding it to the list, the program doesn't even run. (It ran when I took `max` to be an int value).

Edit 2: I just re-ran my code and apparently I have made mistakes even in the insertion. I am sorry for wasting everyone's time and I thank you all for your support.

My insertion code, just in case:

```c
void Insert(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    struct node *temp,*t;
    int total1=b+c+d;
    temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        start=temp;printf("%d", total1);
        start->day=a;
        start->movies=b;
        start->groceries=c;
        start->travel=d;
        start->total=total1;
        start->left=NULL;
        start->right=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
       temp=start;
        while(temp->right!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->right;
        }
        t=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        start->day=a;
        start->movies=b;
        start->groceries=c;
        start->travel=d;
        start->total=total1;
        t->right=NULL;
        t->left=temp;
        temp->right=t;
    }
    printf("\n\nYour expense has been saved successfully!\n\n");
}
```

Comment: No it is not called a branch, it's a field named `day` of the node of your list. Now, what you describe makes me suspect that you do not construct your list correctly, maybe. It would be awesome if you could make a Minimal Reproducible example, with a `main()`, the way you construct your list and the method for finding the max. Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138994/should-we-break-the-default-case-in-switch-statement) of mine that provided a minimal example, in case you want to see an instance of that famous MCVE. :)

Comment: @Bladarc Why does the function named like find_max has the return type void?

Comment: Are you sure, you filled your linked-list correctly? Could you print all elements, before calling this function?

Comment: "Here when I try to print new1->day" -- _Where_ do you print that? After the loop when `new1` should be `NULL`?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, frankly, I referenced a lot of codes posted online, plus, I didn't really need to return any values, so I picked void.

Comment: @Bladarc we always learn. :) Yes, you should edit, and try to post a *minimal complete example*, one that constructs the list, a main method, and also your find max method too.

Comment: @MOehm My bad, I had this as an exam, so I ended up removing that part of the code. I tried printing it right after the end, i.e. ```printf("The maximum spending was: %d",max);``` like this ```printf("The maximum spending was: %d and day was: %d",max, new1->day);```

Comment: Yes, but at that time, `max1` is no longer a valid node. You could, of course, make `max` a node, and then find the max `if (new1->total > max->total) max = new1;`Then you have all information about the max node available at the end.

Comment: @gsamaras I am sorry, I just read that you need a minimal reproducible code. I'll just do that.

Comment: I mistakenly typed max instead of day. My bad again, the lack of sleep is killing me.

Comment: @MOehm Oh, I see. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first version of the code you posted, you just kept the maximum value in an integer. That was fine if you wanted to find the value, but the information which node it was was lost.

In comments, I proposed you make `max` a node. You did that, but made several errors:

- You `max` is uninitialized, which means that bad things will happen. (C-speak for that is "undefined behaviour".) Initialize `max = start`. (Seeing a pointer definition without initialization should raise a red flag. If you don't know what to initialize, at least make it `NULL`, so that you can do checks for `NULL` later. Just writing `struct node *max;` means that `max` has an indeterminate value which you can't even check!
- Then, when you find a better node, don't set `max->total`. That means that you just use the first node as storage for your max, thereby altering the list data, which you don't want. Set the new node:

  ```
  if (new1->total > max->total) max = new1;
  ```

  (If you read my comment closely, that's what I proposed.)

Let's implement that and also fix some semantic issues with the code, see notes below:

```
const struct *node maximumNode()
{
    const struct node *node = start;
    const struct node *max = start;

    while (node != NULL) {
        if(node->total > max->total) {
            max = node;
        }

        node = node->right;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Things to note:

- The function now returns a reference to the node with maximum `total`. The calling code can then print the info or use the node in other ways as it desires, for example:

  ```
  const struct node *max = maximumNode();

  if (node) {
      printf("Max. total of %d was on day %d.\n",
          node->totel, node->day;
  }
  ```

  This is cleaner than doing the printing in the function proper. This wil also allow you to use the same function in other contexts where you need the max. node.
- I've made the node pointers `const struct node *` in your functions. That means that you cannot modify the content of the structs. Just finding the max means that you merely inspect the list, but don'Ät alter it. With this declaration, the compiler would have complained about trying to set `max->total` and you would have seen your error.
- You don't need the first test for `NULL`. When `start`== NULL`, then also`node == NULL`and`max == NULL`. That doesn't change, because the loop isn't entered and we terurn`NULL`, which is the best we can do in that case.
- I've changed the name of the node from `new1` to just `node`. That's a cosmetic change, but `new` to me suggests that a node is being created, but as we're only inspecting, that name may be misleading. Little things count. (Also, I'm a nitpicker.)

Comment: After giving it a lot of thought and time, the program finally works. However in my case, I ended up using ```node->right != NULL``` (for some reason only node didn't work for me) and added some extra lines of codes : ```if (node->next==NULL)
        {
            if (node->total > max->total)
            {
                max = node;
            }
        }``` since the while loop only runs till not NULL and it won't traverse the last node when the pointer becomes NULL.

Answer (score 0):

After spending extended hours and long discussions with @MOehm, this is what I arrived at:
This code is entirely [@MOehm's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979617/m-oehm) and I have made a few minor changes. (Kudos to him)

```
void maximumNode()
{
    const struct node *node = h;
    const struct node *max = h;

    if (h==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nThe expense list is empty!\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
          while (node->next != NULL) {
        if(node->total > max->total) {
            max = node;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
    if (node->next==NULL)
        {
            if (node->total > max->total)
            {
                max = node;
            }
        }
    printf("Max. total of %d was on day %d.\n",max->total, max->day);
    return;
    }

}
```

I have even made some changes in the code for insertion. [I have used and modified the insertion part of the code taken from this website.](https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-doubly-linked-list/)

```
void create()
{
    int data;
    int d,m,g,t;
    int total1=0;
    temp =(struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    printf("\n\nDay: ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    printf("\n\nEnter the expenses:\n1. Movies: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("2. Groceries: ");
    scanf("%d",&g);
    printf("3. Travel: ");
    scanf("%d",&t);
    total1 = m+g+t;
    temp->day=d;
    temp->movies=m;
    temp->groceries=g;
    temp->travel=t;
    temp->total=total1;
}
```

```
void insert2()
{
    if (h == NULL)
    {
        create();
        h = temp;
        temp1 = h;
    }
    else
    {
        create();
        temp1->next = temp;
        temp->prev = temp1;
        temp1 = temp;
    }
}
```

I haven't made any changes in the rest of the code.

Edit 1: Edited in the code for if the list is empty i.e. `h==NULL`

Comment: Okay, so you have "improved" on my single-loop solution by not considering the last node in the list and then adding extra code at the end to treat that last node? Suit yourself. (Your solution will invoke undefined behaviour when `h` is null, by the way.)

Comment: @MOehm I didn't 'improve' it, I never said that. When I tried your code, it didn't work for me. (Must be some error I am not able to debug), if that was what came out of it, I am sorry; I really didn't mean to offend you. Yeah, I just checked that, since I used your code for that (and I forgot to define ```h```, again 3 am can only bring you so much), I'll just edit it in. I accepted your answer for a reason; I posted what worked for me for my future reference.

Comment: @MOehm I am getting this error: ```expected ' { ' before ' * ' token.``` (I am putting it in ```void maximumNode()``` ). I don't understand how to fix it.