# C++ switch empty default case

Tags: c++, syntax

I think I've been led astray by lax compilers in the past.  I've been going along happily with something like

```
int main()
{
    int g = 3;
    switch (g) {
           case 1: ++g;
                   break;
           case 2: g+=2;
                   break;
           default:
                   // do nothing 
    }
    return g;
}
```

compiling with no problem.  But more recently I've [gotten compiler errors](https://godbolt.org/z/d6cjxr).

Modifying the default case to

```
           default:
                   // do nothing 
                   break;
    }
```

or even

```
           default:; // do nothing 
    }
```

makes the compiler happy.  [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) is not clear. The syntax puts a statement after `default` which seems to imply that *something* is needed after `default:`.  This could even be an empty statement, so you don't even need the `break`, just a bare semicolon.  The section on [statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements)s isn't clear on whether a label can appear at the end of a compound statement.

So, is a switch with nothing after `default:` but before the closing brace well-formed or not?  Was it perhaps OK in an old version of C or C++?

(Note this is **not** about whether to include a default or not. Also, you need to assume that it's legitimate for the default to do nothing. Also [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138994/should-we-break-the-default-case-in-switch-statement) is close but no cigar.)